# Calling Errback with IdentifyTask (ArcGIS)

Tags: javascript, error-handling, arcgis

I'm trying to use the [`IdentifyTask`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/identifytask-amd.html) for ArcGIS and I am aware that it is failing if the map service is incorrect. Now I want to handle the error. However, I'm not entirely sure of how I'm supposed to use the `errback` parameter to handle an error on the call.

This is what I have so far.

```
var serviceName = "http://cnn.com"; //ensure failure of the execute
var identifyTask = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask(serviceName);
var task = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);
```

How would I go about handling errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add two callback functions in the call to the `execute` method. Here is the example.

```
var callback = function (results) {
    //handle results
}
var errback = function (error) {
    //handle error
}

var task = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams, callback, errback);
```